# Docker port issue

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am developing an application which runs on docker containers. I have two node js applications where one is running on port number 5000 and another on 8888 in the docker. I would like to send http request to the node app's route which runs on port 8888 from node app 5000. but it is not working. but when I tried to access the same api end point of port 8888 application it is working fine on browser as well as a none dockerize node js app. can anyone help me to resolve the issue? below is my docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  node-sdc-service:
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev

    environment:
            CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'

    container_name: node-sdc
    tty: true
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:3000:3000"
      - "0.0.0.0:4000:4000"
      - "0.0.0.0:5000:5000"
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app


  yolov5-service:
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile-yolo

    environment:
            CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'

    container_name: yolo 
    tty: true
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8888:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/server
      - ./training_data:/usr/src/coco
      - ./yolo_runs:/usr/src/app/runs



      


  mongo-sdc-service:
    # image: mongo:4.2-bionic
    image: mongo:5.0-focal
    # restart: always
    container_name: mongo-sdc
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1004
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: sdc 
    volumes:
        - mongo-sdc-storage:/data/db

    ports:
      - 27020:27017

volumes:
    mongo-sdc-storage:
```

Comment: can you explain how are you trying to access ?

Comment: @George I am trying to access using the http request method in node js

Answer (score 0):

You should expose both port in Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 8888
```

In docker-compose file use this config

```
   ports:
     - target: 5000
       published: 5000
       protocol: tcp
       mode: host
     - target: 8888
       published: 8888
       protocol: tcp
       mode: host
```

Comment: but I can access the ports in browser without any issue.

Comment: You could use load balancing service like Haproxy or Nginx revers proxy to route traffic

Answer (score 0):

Each container is added to the same docker network from your compose. Now since it resides on the same network the PORT that you need to query is 5000 from within your node-sdc-service and not 8888. more information can be found here
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Comment: this is not calling the particular api

Answer (score 0):

The issue is sorted by calling the 8888 port with local wifi ip